# Azure pipeline nested parameter index

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

How do I get the x element of a nested Azure DevOps pipeline parameter?

```
parameters:
 - name: environment
   type: object
   default:
     development:
       description: Development env
       vaults:
         Vault-1: Vault-1-Connection
         Vault-2: Vault-2-Connection
```

In my case I want to get the key and the value of the first element in the `vaults` sub-object.

This doesn't work:

```
${{ each env in parameters.environment }}:
  ${{ env.vaults[0].key }}
  ${{ env.vaults[0].value }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the code as below to get the key and value of the first element in vaults sub-object. Please note: Vault-1 seems is unexpected symbol while parsing pipeline YAML, thus I replace it with Vault1.

```
steps:
- script: echo ${{parameters.environment.development.vaults.Vault1}}   # echo nested object value

        
- ${{ each pair in parameters.environment.development.vaults }}:       # echo nested object key and value
  - ${{ if eq(pair.key,'Vault1')}}:
    - script: echo "${{ pair.key }}, ${{ pair.value }}"
```

Comment: @Mihaimyh, is there any updates for this question? Please feel free to let me know whether the answers above can help you and feel free to comment~ Just a remind to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).